# Number of elements not increasing after appending to list

Tags: tcl

```
% set l1 {}
% lappend l1 one
one
% lappend l1 two
one two
% puts $l1
one two
% llength l1
1
```

But length of the list l1 should be 2, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `llength $l1`. Else, `tcl` will think like `l1` as a single element list.

`$` symbol is used to access the variables in `tcl`. That is why you have to use `$l1` which will point to the list named `l1`

Comment: Strictly, `$` is used to _read_ variables. Writing them requires the name (hence `set a "an example"` and not `set $a "an example"`).